# authenticate django built in user using custom field

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have model that has one to one relation with django's built in User model. Due to some reason i have added a custom field in my model with name "password_crypt" that supports "pbkdf2_sha512" which is longer than django's built-in field that is i guess 128. So i want to authenticate my user using my custom field but want the rest of the things to work in the same way django's built-in User provides. Token etc

How can i authenticate model Object that has one to one relation with  django  built-in User using custom field "password_crypt" in new model.

I am using python 2.7, django 1.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write custom [auth backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SettingsBackend:
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        if username and password:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                password_valid = check_password(password, user.onetoone.password_crypt)   
                if password_valid:
                    return user
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

and add it to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
   'mybackend.SettingsBackend',
   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
```

Comment: Can i write this authenticate method in my model ? having one to one with built in User

Comment: @DaniyalSyed it would be better to add new file for this called auth_backends or something like this, but it is not required.

Comment: I will try this and let you know. @neverwalkaloner